# Delphi TClientDataset SQL Server RowVersion

Tags: sql-server, delphi, tclientdataset, rowversion

Does anyone have any experience using SQL Server 's `RowVersion` column with `TClientDataset`? Specifically, I need to get the `RowVersion` value back on insert. It seems to get the `RowVersion` value back on updates but a newly inserted row it does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to involve a similar problem to when you need to use a CDS with
a SqlServer table which has an Identity field, where the value in the field
is set by the server, so you don't know it during the CDS-side insert operation.  One way to do that is explained in this article
http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/20847.  It involves
assigning a temporary, negative, value to the Identity field in the CDS
in the `OnNewRecord` event, and then using the `Refresh` method of the CDS to
retrieve the server-side identity field value once the new record has been
posted to the server by calling `ApplyUpdates`.

In D7, which I'm using for this answer as a sort of lowest common denominator,
this technique seems to work fine to a RowVersion field as well.  An
extract from a sample project is below.  To get it working, I had to define
the RowVersion field as an `ftBytes` field with a size of 8, and to change
the `ProviderFlags` to exclude `pfInWhere` and `pfInUpdate` from the
AdoQuery's identity field, ID.

The `RowVerStr` field in the CDS is just to display the value legibly in a TDBGrid.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ADOConnection1: TADOConnection;
    ADOQuery1: TADOQuery;
    DataSetProvider1: TDataSetProvider;
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    DBNavigator1: TDBNavigator;
    ADOQuery1ID: TAutoIncField;  //  The ID field is an Identity field on the server
    ADOQuery1IntValue: TIntegerField;  //  a user field
    CDS1: TClientDataSet;
    CDS1ID: TAutoIncField;
    CDS1IntValue: TIntegerField;
    CDS1RowVersion: TBytesField;
    CDS1RowVerStr: TStringField;  //  just for display, fkInternalCalc, size = 20
    ADOQuery1RowVersion: TBytesField;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure CDS1AfterPost(DataSet: TDataSet);
    procedure CDS1AfterDelete(DataSet: TDataSet);
    procedure CDS1NewRecord(DataSet: TDataSet);
    procedure CDS1AfterInsert(DataSet: TDataSet);
    procedure CDS1CalcFields(DataSet: TDataSet);
  public
    FID : Integer;  //  To generate temporary value for CDS identity field
    function NextID : Integer;
  end;

[...]

function GetRowVerString(V : Variant) : String;
var
  i,
  Dim,
  Min,
  Max : Integer;
  i64 : Int64;
begin
  Result := '';
  if not VarIsArray(V) then Exit;
  Dim := VarArrayDimCount(V);
  Max := VarArrayHighBound(V, Dim);
  Min := VarArrayLowBound(V, Dim);

  for i := 0 to 7 do
    Int64Rec(i64).Bytes[i] := V[i];
  Result := IntToStr(i64);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //  CDS1ID is an ftAutoInc field, so we need to remove its read-only flag so
  //  that we can assign it a temporary negative value in the OnNewRecord event
  CDS1ID.ReadOnly := False;

  AdoQuery1RowVersion.ProviderFlags := AdoQuery1RowVersion.ProviderFlags - [pfInWhere, pfInUpdate];

  CDS1.Open;
  Caption := IntToStr(CDS1.RecordCount);
end;

procedure TForm1.CDS1AfterPost(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  if CDS1.ApplyUpdates(0) = 0 then
    CDS1.Refresh;
end;

procedure TForm1.CDS1AfterDelete(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  CDS1.ApplyUpdates(-1);
end;

function TForm1.NextID: Integer;
begin
  Dec(FID);
  Result := FID;
end;

procedure TForm1.CDS1NewRecord(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  CDS1.FieldByName('ID').AsInteger := NextID;
  CDS1.FieldByName('IntValue').AsInteger := Random(100);
end;

procedure TForm1.CDS1AfterInsert(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  CDS1.Post;
end;

procedure TForm1.CDS1CalcFields(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  CDS1RowVerStr.AsString := GetRowVerString(CDS1RowVersion.Value);
end;
```

Comment: `rowversion` is a [synonym (actually replacement) for `timestamp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql).

Comment: @MartynA: your solution does work.  Seems excessively chatty, but I am not able to implement it in my environment due to restrictions placed upon me beyond my control.